# How do you return all nodes related within 5 hops of the original using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a user searching for a node, and I would like to return that node, a set of all the relationships that were found, and a list of the related nodes. I tried something like this...

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.uuid = <uuid>
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r*..5]-(c)
RETURN distinct(n) as parentNode, collect(r) as links, collect(c) as nodes
```

This however doesn't work because the links come back as a list within a list for some reason. The result from this looks like (using the node module)...

```
[ //<-- I don't need a list
  {
    "parentNode": {...parent node stuff..},
    "links": [
      [  //<-- This is what I mean by 2 lists
        {...link stuff...}
      ],
      [  //<-- This is what I mean by 2 lists
        {...link stuff...}
      ],
    ],
    "nodes":[
        {...node stuff..}
    ]
  }
]
```

I would expect this to look like...

```
{
    "parentNode": {...parent node stuff..},
    "links": [
      {...link stuff...},
      {...link stuff...},
    ],
    "nodes":[
      {...node stuff..}
    ]
}
```

If I try a return function that is a little simpler...

```
RETURN n as parentNode, r as links, c as nodes
```

parent node is repeated for each entry.

How would I properly return this information?

**update**

So looking a bit more it seems the issue is with the `..5` this returns 1 set for each node.

So say node 1 is related to node 2 which is related to node 3. And for now say that instead of `..5` we use `..2`. The query

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.number = 1
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r*..2]-(c)
RETURN c as nodes, collect(r) as sublinks
```

Would return something like

```
[
  {
    "nodes": {..node 2 info...},
    "sublinks":[
       [
          {.. 2 relationships (one to 1 and one to 3)...}
       ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "nodes": {..node 3 info...},
    "sublinks":[
       [
          {.. 1 relationships (one to 2)..}
       ]
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see the relationship between node 2 and 3 is grabbed 2 times. Also node 1 is not returned. These are the types of issues I am trying to avoid.

Comment: What do you want to return?  If you collect the relationships, you get a list as you said.  If you don't, then you get a different relationship each time, hence your `n` is duplicated . What do you want your output to look like because those two choices cover your main 2 options.

Comment: You say you want to return a set of relationships -- collect(r) is a set of relationships (a list really).  So please be more specific about your desired output.

Comment: Update this with more info about what I expect vs. what I am seeing

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things that you can do.  The first thing I would suggest though, if you have a large dataset:
 * If you aren't using labels, use the Neo4j internal ID to find your `n` node
 * Alternatively you can use a label and create an index for the `uuid` property for that label so that you can find it quickly.

That said, I don't think it generally makes sense to give a label to a variable length path like that.  With variable length paths you generally want to assign the whole path to a variable like this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.uuid = <uuid>
OPTIONAL MATCH path=(n)-[*1..5]-(c)
RETURN path
```

That will work, though for any path of length x > 2 you'll get another x - 2 paths which are subsets of that path.  If that's what you want you can return each result node and the path to that node:

```
RETURN c, path
```

Alternatively you might want just the set of start/end nodes which represent the relationships.  You can get that with a bit of processing:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.uuid = <uuid>
OPTIONAL MATCH path=(n)-[*1..5]-(c)
WITH rels(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH DISTINCT rel
RETURN startnode(rel), endnode(rel), type(rel)
```

Does that help to answer your question?

Edit: replace path=n... with path=(n)...

Comment: The indexing sounds like a great idea. So there are 2 main issues with this solution, however, I think you might be on to something (although it may be inefficient). First, just returning path still returns the duplicate records. Second they are links and not the actual record. That being said perhaps the solution is just to take the end node and start node like you said in the last example. However, the last example doesn't return the nodes as well, however, maybe despite the extra network traffic it is worth it to make those separate calls.

Comment: Is rels(path) slang for relationships(path)? I didn't even know that was possible

Comment: If you want to be a bit more efficient you can do `RETURN ID(startnode(rel)), ID(endnode(rel)), type(rel)` to just return the node IDs.  Also about `rels` I'm not sure because I think I've always used `rels`, but they seems to be aliases ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting into 3 separate queries...

```
MATCH (n {uuid: {uuid}}) return n as node

MATCH path=(n{uuid: {uuid}})-[r*..'+hops+']-(c)
WITH rels(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH DISTINCT rel
RETURN rel

MATCH path=(n {uuid: {uuid}})-[r*..'+hops+']-(c)
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
WITH DISTINCT node
RETURN node
```

This seems to allow me to aggregate client side to what I need. I won't accept because there has to be a better way.